# How does a terminated Flutter App receive method channel call from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, flutter-method-channel

**I want to know how a terminated Flutter App receives method channel call from BroadcastReceiver which starts the app.**

https://github.com/k-nakabayashi/flutter_method_channel/blob/main/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flutter_method_channel/PhoneCallReceiver.kt#L49

**Q1: What happens to the following NG Case? and What can I do?**

OK Case : this running app can make PhoneCallReceiver "PhoneCallChannelCtrl.instance?.sendToFLutter(phoneNumber)"

NG Case: this terminated app can't do it. (this app can just be started.

Detail:

This app is started by PhoneCallReceiver@booApp and then, MainActivity@configureFlutterEngine set MethodChannel (which is set by PhoneCallChannelCtrl@setup).

**Q2 (alternative):  How do a terminated flutter side catch this intent?**